# need help in resolving emoji-mart.css error

Tags: reactjs

i am facing an error

> ERROR in ./src/pages/components/Messenger.jsx 5:0-39
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'emoji-mart/css/emoji-mart.css' in 'F:\job assignments\Chat-box project\client\src\pages\components'

i already installed emoji-mart in my project already tried this

```
import 'emoji-mart/dist/emoji-mart.css';
```

but error stays same

my code

```
import 'emoji-mart/dist/emoji-mart.css';
import 'emoji-mart/css/emoji-mart.css';
npm install emoji-mart
```

i already try importing above 2 lines already install the package but error stays same